# mysql setup on macos

Tags: mysql, macos

I just started attempting to learn node.js and mysql on my local machine. I've installed mysql using homebrew.

When trying to set the password for the root, I get the following response:

```
Thaddeuss-iMac➜  ~  ᐅ  mysqladmin -u root password 'password'

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed

error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

**However** trying to set a password this way, it appears like there already is a password:

```
Thaddeuss-iMac➜  ~  ᐅ  mysqladmin -u root -p 

password

Enter password: 

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed

error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

The most recent uninstallation lines were this:

```
Thaddeuss-iMac➜  ~  ᐅ  sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
Password:

Thaddeuss-iMac➜  ~  ᐅ  sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*

Thaddeuss-iMac➜  ~  ᐅ  sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM

Thaddeuss-iMac➜  ~  ᐅ  sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*

Thaddeuss-iMac➜  ~  ᐅ  rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
zsh: no matches found: /Users/thaddeuspinch/Library/PreferencePanes/My*

Thaddeuss-iMac➜  ~  ᐅ  sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
zsh: no matches found: /Library/Receipts/mysql*

Thaddeuss-iMac➜  ~  ᐅ  sudo rm -rf 
/Library/Receipts/MySQL*
zsh: no matches found: /Library/Receipts/MySQL*

Thaddeuss-iMac➜  ~  ᐅ  sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

I've uninstalled mysql numerous ways and reinstalled both through homebrew and the .dmg from Oracle for my version of OSX (10.12.6). Consistently getting the same issue. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't have a password at first. Try just `mysqladmin -u root`. If that doesn't work, search up "reset mysql password" and you'll find a bunch of clear tutorials.

Comment: I think I found one core issue, I tried installing on my macbook and I was able to locate the mysql option in the system preferences and define a password for the user 'root', which is not available on my imac. Any idea on getting the mysql program to show up in the system prefs?

Comment: As you've installed it via Homebrew, it's not likely to be picked up natively by OSX in the Preferences. It'll be easier to follow https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html.